# Any way to get architecture document from django framework

Tags: django, django-models

I m writting two applications in django framework, and i would like to know if there are any tools available with which i can get entire architecture diagram of the project itself?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: you mean like this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Comment: No, not that, If i design my own application with django framework, i need to generate a Architecture diagram that replicates my application.

Comment: What do you mean architecture diagram? You can generate a diagram of your model layout using `graphviz` and `django-extensions`: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoGraphviz

Comment: When you say architecture do you mean the views\urls, the models, the different applications for a project or what? you need to be a little more clearer in your question